# iOS swift displaying image with text on uilabel

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uilabel, overlay

In my app i need to display the text content along with image in UILabel like this [image]

but i am only able to display text along with image like this text string in UILabel is starting from the bottom of the image. But i need to start the text from the top.
[image]

I am using the following code please help me to display the image with text in proper format.

```
let topDesc = responseDict?["description_top"]?.string ?? ""
                    
                    // Create Attachment
                    let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
                    imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named:"no-image")
                    // Set bound to reposition
                    let imageOffsetY: CGFloat = 0
                    imageAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: imageOffsetY, width: 130, height: 92)
                    // Create string with attachment
                    let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
                    // Initialize mutable string
                    let completeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
                    // Add image to mutable string
                    completeText.append(attachmentString)
                    // Add your text to mutable string
                    let textAfterIcon = NSAttributedString(string: topDesc)
                    completeText.append(textAfterIcon)
                    self.topContentLbl.textAlignment = .center
                    self.topContentLbl.attributedText = completeText
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a `UITextView` and `.exclusionPaths`.

Here, the yellow-background text view is 353-points wide and I define a 116x80 rectangular `UIBezierPath`:

```
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 116.0, height: 80.0))]
```

[image]

By setting `.isScrollEnabled = false` on the text view, it will size its own height based on the text.

Now, all we need to do is add the rounded-rect view and the image view on top of it.

To get your **exact** layout - using a single string of text - will be a little difficult.

As you see in the above image, the text flows around the exclusion path, but the image you posted looks more like this:

[image]

To get that, I added two line-feeds in the string:

```
advice and guidance to you.\n\nOur Personal stylist will work
```

However, unless you're writing the copy to match the available space, it might look like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

If you *need* the paragraph break as shown in your image, your best option would probably be to embed a special character (or, for example, the double line-break) and split the string at run-time to fill two labels laid out as desired.

Here's a quick example showing how to use the `.exclusionPaths`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        let font: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .regular)
        
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        // let's add a little extra line height
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2.0
        
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
        ]
        
        let str: String = "Online styling consultation service is a service where a professional stylist provides fashion advice and guidance to you over video calls, email, or Whatsapp. Our Personal stylist will work with you to understand your personal style, body shape, and wardrobe goals, and will provide recommendations for clothing, accessories, and outfits that will suit your needs."

        let attStr = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attributes)
        
        textView.attributedText = attStr
        
        textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 116.0, height: 80.0))]
        
        // so we can see the frames
        textView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way to do it, declare your objects and set constraints:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

let yourImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "9")
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return iv
}()

let bottomTextView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.backgroundColor = .white
    tv.textColor = .black
    tv.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return tv
}()

let rightmLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()

let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Online Styling Consultation"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label
}()

let bgView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9690894485, green: 0.8088869452, blue: 0.9875240922, alpha: 1)
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    v.clipsToBounds = true
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return v
}()

let myString = "Monthly price reflects net monthly payment, after application of AT&T trade‑in credit applied over 36 months with purchase of an iPhone 14 Pro, iPhone 14 Pro Max, iPhone 14, or iPhone 14 Plus and trade‑in of eligible smartphone. Receive credit with purchase of an iPhone 14 Pro or iPhone 14 Pro Max of either $1000, $700, or $350 (based upon the model and condition of your trade‑in smartphone). Receive credit with purchase of an iPhone 14 or iPhone 14 Plus of either $700 or $350 (based upon the model and condition of your trade‑in smartphone). "

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    // split string in two different string
    let words = myString.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let halfLength = words.count / 6 // split string
    let firstHalf = words[0..<halfLength].joined(separator: " ")
    let secondHalf = words[halfLength..<words.count].joined(separator: " ")

    print(firstHalf)
    print(secondHalf)
    
    rightmLabel.text = firstHalf
    bottomTextView.text = secondHalf
    
    view.addSubview(bgView)
    bgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    bgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    bgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true
    bgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(yourImageView)
    yourImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    yourImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    yourImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    yourImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(bottomTextView)
    bottomTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    bottomTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourImageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    bottomTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    // create your right label in a stackView
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, rightmLabel])
    stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 2
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourImageView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomTextView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true     
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: here you are using 2 separate strings for two labels. but i have only text 1 string which i have to display in label. is there any other way to split the string according to the label size/space then the rest will displayed to the bottom label

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap I don't know and have never seen the solution you are trying to recreate in swift, but never say never... With my code you have control over all three labels: title, bottom and right including the line spacing between title and right label ( stackView.spacing), but I repeat I don't know about how to split a text as you say...

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap take a look, I update my answer